# centralized powershell backup script

Tags: powershell

We're needing a powershell script to backup a folder from 3 remote servers:

server1
server2
server3

same source path on each remote server:
c:\backupfiles

To a central local folder with today's date for each:
c:\allbackups\server1<DATE>
c:\allbackups\server2<DATE>
c:\allbackups\server3<DATE>

What's the cleanest way to do that?
thanks,

Comment: the cleanest way is to use robocopy. you can call that from in a PoSh script, so it can be set up fairly directly.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey If you give that as an answer, it can be accepted as such.

Comment: @Xalorous - should it be brain dead simple OR should it include some simple error handling?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey both. ;)  But "cleanest" would match up with braindead simple.

Comment: @Xalorous - i think i managed to meet that criteria in my Answer ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

here's a way to do the job. [*grin*] it is a tad more that what was requested, and yet is not fully filled out since it lacks proper error handling. in any case ... here is what it does ...

- creates the server computer list
- sets the various constants
- creates the destination root dir
  here is one "lacks-error-handling" point - no check is made to *ensure* the dir is created and is writable.
- iterates thru the computer list
- checks for the remote source dir
- if NOT there, writes a warning to the screen
  another place where this is a tad lacking. you may want to add the missing sources to a $Var or error file.
- if YES there ...
- builds the full backup dest dir
- creates it &ignores any errors
  yet another bit of poor error handling. [*sigh ...*]
- builds the parameters for `robocopy` into an array
- calls RC with the above parameter splat
  look up `Get-Help about_Splatting` for a really neato feature. [*grin*]
- finishes iterating thru the computer list

the code ...

```
$ComputerList = @(
    'LocalHost'
    '127.0.0.1'
    $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

# swap the `#` on these two lines to test "no source found"
$SourceDir = 'd$\Temp'
#$SourceDir = 'd$\Temp\NotThere'

$RootDestDir = "$env:TEMP\Backups"
if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $RootDestDir))
    {
    $Null = New-Item -Path $RootDestDir -ItemType 'Directory'
    }

$FileSpec = '*.*'

$TimeStamp = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$Subject = 'RC_Backup'
$LogFileName = -join ($Subject, '_-_', $TimeStamp, '.log')
$FullLogFileName = Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath $LogFileName


foreach ($CL_Item in $ComputerList)
    {
    $RemoteSourceDir = '\\{0}\{1}' -f $CL_Item, $SourceDir
    if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $RemoteSourceDir)
        {
        $FullDestDir = Join-Path -Path $RootDestDir -ChildPath ('{0}_-_{1}' -f $CL_Item, $TimeStamp)
        $Null = mkdir -Path $FullDestDir -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'

        $RC_Params = @(
            $RemoteSourceDir
            $FullDestDir
            $FileSpec 
            # put your current options below
            "/Log:$FullLogFileName"
            '/NP'
            '/E'
            # comment out the next line to suppress on-screen output
            '/TEE'
            )
        robocopy $RC_Params
        }
        else
        {
        Write-Warning ('    [ {0} ] was not found on [ {1} ].' -f $RemoteSourceDir, $CL_Item)
        }

    } # end >>> foreach ($CL_Item in $ComputerList)
```

output if the sources are not reachable ...

```
WARNING:     [ \\LocalHost\d$\Temp\NotThere ] was not found on [ LocalHost ].
WARNING:     [ \\127.0.0.1\d$\Temp\NotThere ] was not found on [ 127.0.0.1 ].
WARNING:     [ \\MySysName\d$\Temp\NotThere ] was not found on [ ZK_01 ].
```

truncated output for a successful run ...

```
Log File : C:\Temp\RC_Backup_-_2020-07-13.log

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Mon Jul 13 16:11:34 2020

   Source : \\LocalHost\d$\Temp\
     Dest : C:\Temp\Backups\LocalHost_-_2020-07-13\

    Files : *.*
    
  Options : *.* /TEE /S /E /COPY:DAT /NP /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                       1    \\LocalHost\d$\Temp\
        New File           7.7 m    testing.zip
      New Dir          2    \\LocalHost\d$\Temp\1\
        New File          422446    Lee_CHOICES_2017-07-07
        New File           89854    Lee_CHOICES_2017-07-07.H3M
      New Dir         23    \\LocalHost\d$\Temp\2\
        New File             549    Archive_Backup_to_NAS_-_Update_One_Way_[daily] 2016-03-07 010000.log
        New File            5119    Data_-_Update_One_Way_[daily] 2016-03-07 020000.log
        New File          322186    Documents_-_Update_One_Way_[monthly] 2016-02-01 030000 [Error].log
        New File          367981    Documents_-_Update_One_Way_[monthly] 2016-03-01 030000 [Error].log
        New File           58906    Email_-_Update_One_Way_[monthly] 2016-02-01 040000 [Error].log
        New File           59151    Email_-_Update_One_Way_[monthly] 2016-03-01 040004 [Error].log
        New File           75434    Generic_Backup_to_NAS_-_Mirror_One_Way_[daily] 2016-03-07 050000 [Warning].log

[*...snip...*] 

        New File             326    desktop.ini
        New File          25.0 m    Wildlife.wmv

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :       234       233         1         0         0         0
   Files :       320       320         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :  290.15 m  290.15 m         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:06   0:00:06                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :            49624024 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :            2839.509 MegaBytes/min.

   Ended : Mon Jul 13 16:11:40 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea of simple.

```
$ServerList = @( Server1 Server2 Server3 )
$AllBackups = "c:\allbackups"
$TimeStamp = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
$SourceFolder = "C$\backupfiles"

foreach ($server in ServerList) {
    Copy-Item -Path "\\$server\$SourceFolder" -Destination "$AllBackups\$server-$Timestamp" -Recurse
}
```